# Is there an R package which implements weighted maximum likelihood for Rasch models?

Tags: r, psychometrics, rasch, item-response-theory

Is there a package in R which implements the weighted maximum likelihood method (Warm, 1996) for estimating the person parameters in Rasch Models?

Answer (score 7):

Looks like I'm quite late to the game here, but the `mirt` package package can estimate WLE scores for dichotomous and polytomous models. You start by fitting, say, a graded response model to your data (or whatever your model may be, PCM, generalised PCM, nominal, rating scale, etc; see ?mirt for the possible options) then compute either a table summary of the factor scores or a complete dataset using the option `full.scores = TRUE` (the default):

```
#E.g. with 4-item Science data
> library('mirt')
> (mod <- mirt(Science, 1))

Call:
mirt(data = Science, model = 1)

Full-information item factor analysis with 1 factor(s).
Converged within 1e-04 tolerance after 36 EM iterations.
mirt version: 1.23 
M-step optimizer: BFGS 
EM acceleration: Ramsay
Number of rectangular quadrature: 61

Log-likelihood = -1608.87
Estimated parameters: 16 
AIC = 3249.739; AICc = 3251.19
BIC = 3313.279; SABIC = 3262.512
G2 (239) = 213.56, p = 0.8804
RMSEA = 0, CFI = 1, TLI = 1.193

> tablescores <- fscores(mod, method='WLE', full.scores=FALSE)
> head(tablescores)

     Comfort Work Future Benefit         F1     SE_F1
[1,]       1    1      1       1 -5.6980733 1.5782656
[2,]       1    3      2       1 -2.1191038 0.6332802
[3,]       1    4      2       3 -1.1387624 0.6557002
[4,]       1    4      3       1 -0.8489387 0.7000115
[5,]       2    1      1       1 -4.0112458 1.1423935
[6,]       2    1      2       4 -1.8957020 0.6698434
```

There also is the more traditional ML, MAP, and EAP scores too, in case you wanted to compare.

Answer (score 4):

To the best of my knowledge (though I would be happy to be corrected) the main package in R for Rasch models is eRm, which fits the person and item parameters through conditional maximum likelihood. It interfaces to nlm, which is a general function for non linear optimisation so you might be able to code up the method yourself.  If you install eRm and run the `vignette("eRm")` you'll get quite a readable introduction.

If you are just looking for IRT methods (not specifically Rasch models) you could check out ltm, which does 2 and 3 parameter models, and mokken which carries out non parametric IRT. I believe there is a package mirt which fits multivariate IRT models, but I have not used it so I cannot say too much about it.

Also, if you need to find a particular function in R, use the sos package.
Install it from the usual sources, load it and then use the `findFn()` command.

For example, findFn("mixed Rasch") brings up quite a number of results, some of which may be useful to you.

Comment: I was unable to turn up anything as well.  To the OP: the Task View on psychometric models may be of interest: http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Psychometrics.html  It doesn't seem that "weighted maximum likelihood" is mentioned anywhere in the packages' documentations, but I'm not an expert on this matter, so I may be missing something.

Comment: By the way, the `eRm` vignette mentions that the Warm (1989) approach will be added to a future version - see p. 11 of http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eRm/vignettes/eRm.pdf.

Comment: @Iterator - thanks I had a feeling that i'd heard the term somewhere in the R documentation before.

Comment: @richiemorrisroe - Thank you very much for your help, I think there isn't really any package for weighted MLE, I've checked all the packages in the Task View. So I really might have to code up the method myself.

Comment: Also I haven't found any library for mixed-Rasch in and Hybrid Models- Is it really possible that there isn't anything in R for these useful and rather common models?

Comment: @Paul You might want to consider [lme4](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html) (see this [JSS paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v39/i12)), although it relies on MLL (and not CLL like in eRm). The [JSS vol. 20](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v20) is also worth to check for general approach in using R for psychometrics; von Davier and coll. published a good book on mixture Rasch models and released the `mdltm` software (not R), see e.g. [here](http://www.springerlink.com/content/h54064381p1217tr/).

Comment: I write it in R and Java. Can send you the code but it's ugly... Not a Newton Raphson but a "split half" search.

Comment: @pbneau - Do you have the code for WML or Mixed Rasch or Hybrid models? And have you coded up dichotomous or polytomous (partial cretit) Rasch model? Well, in any case, I'd love to see it!!! paul (dot) illg (at) gmail (dot) com

Comment: @chl - Unfortunately my data is polytomous (hopefully ordinal), so Ime4 won't work for me. but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed WCML is very interessant for estimation of CAT results when perfect are possible (for the first items).

So weighted maximum likelihood method for ability estimation has been written by David Magis in his package for simulation of CATs in R.

The function is called **thetaEst** in his package **catR**. Estimation is possible for one to 4 parameters models. I advice you to use his package(s).

But WCML can lead to misestimation of ability. See for example *Precision of Warm’s Weighted Likelihood Estimation
of Ability for a Polytomous Model in CAT*, Shudong Wang and Tianyou Wang, ACT Research Reports (1999)

Comment: Unfortunately thetaEst only estimates person parameters for dichotomous data... my data is polytomous.